# How to trace or log Javascript errors on Javascript files in a page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, error-handling, runtime-error, dom-events

I am developing one plug-in in jQuery/Javascript. In that I need to log Javascript errors of all Javascript files in a page. I tried this code to log and pass this to databae using Ajax

```
error_log=new Array();
 window.onerror=function(msg, url, line)
{ 

error_log.push("Message:" + msg + "-------URL:" + url + "-------Line:" + line);
  
}
```

Its working, but I need some more options and suggestions about logging js Errors.

I need the array containing Javascript errors in a page.

Please help me to improve the capturing errors in a page.

P.S: I don't need any js tracking websites like **jslogger, airbrake, errorception, exceptionhub**

Answer (score 0):

You could insert the errors into your database and then show them on a page
Using Jquery to send an ajax request.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you need this error logging to improve *your development process* (or is it the purpose of your plugin to log all errors on the page?)

**In this case**

use your browsers **developer tools**. They provide wide more features than error logging with `console.log`. You can set breakpoints (even conditional ones), inspect your code at runtime, etc.

http://devtoolsecrets.com/ is a great place to find more about your dev tools. (I'd recommend Chrome as its dev tools are truly sophisticated, but Firefox with [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) also works quite well).

Answer (score -1):

This whole example is provided by perishablepress.com. This is not my own work. I just provide the source.
Its mostly for PHP Errors, but you can easily alter it to save your JS Errors.

https://perishablepress.com/ajax-error-log/

Working example (open in new window):

https://perishablepress.com/tools/ajaxlog/

Steps explained in the provided link to solve your problem:

**Step 1**

Create your Database.

**Step 2**

Create Error-logging page:

```
<?php
/*
Dynamic Error Logging by Jeff Starr @ Perishable Press
Project URL: https://perishablepress.com/ajax-error-log/
License: GNU General Public License
Version: 1.1
*/

// database credentials
$hostname = "hostname";
$database = "database";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";

// site URL (no trailing slash!)
$website = "http://example.com";

// send proper headers for 404
header("HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found");
header("Status: 404 Not Found");

// set some server variables
$logtime = date("F jS Y, h:ia", time() - 10800);
$request = $site . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$referer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
$qstring = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
$address = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$agent   = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
$error   = "404"; // for other errors

// connect to database
$dbcon = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password)
 or die("Couldn't connect to SQL Server on $dbhost");
$selected = mysql_select_db($database, $dbcon)
 or die("Couldn't open database $database");

// sanitize server variables
$logtime_esc = mysql_real_escape_string($logtime);
$request_esc = mysql_real_escape_string($request);
$referer_esc = mysql_real_escape_string($referer);
$qstring_esc = mysql_real_escape_string($qstring);
$address_esc = mysql_real_escape_string($address);
$agent_esc   = mysql_real_escape_string($agent);

// insert record and close database
$query  = "INSERT INTO `error_log` (logtime,request,referer,qstring,address,agent,error) ";
$query .= "VALUES ('$logtime_esc','$request_esc','$referer_esc','$qstring_esc','$address_esc','$agent_esc','$error')";
mysql_query($query);
mysql_close($dbcon);

// and finally output the html
?><html>
    <head><title>404 - Not Found</title></head>
    <body id="error-404">
        <div class="left">
            <div class="post">
                <h1>Error 404 &mdash; Not Found</h1>
                <p>The requested resource was not found on this server.</p>
                <div class="content">
                    <p><?php echo "Requested URL: " . $website . $request_esc; ?></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Step 3**

"The next step is to instruct the server to use the custom 404.php file instead of the default error page. With Apache, this is possible with a single line added to your site’s root .htaccess file:"

```
ErrorDocument 404 /ajax-error-log/404.php
```

**Step 4**

Verify functionality

**Step 5**

Create dynamic logging

```
   <?php
    /*
    Dynamic Error Logging by Jeff Starr @ Perishable Press
    Project URL: https://perishablepress.com/ajax-error-log/
    License: GNU General Public License
    Version: 1.1
    */
    
    // database credentials
    $hostname = "hostname";
    $database = "database";
    $username = "username";
    $password = "password";
    
    // site URL (no trailing slash!)
    $website = "http://example.com";
    
    // connect to server
    $dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password)
     or die('Could not connect to SQL Server on $hostname');
    
    // select the database
    $selected = mysql_select_db($database, $dbhandle)
     or die('Could not open database $database');
    
    // create the sql query
    $query = 'SELECT id,logtime,request,referer,qstring,address,agent,error
     FROM error_log ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 50'; // defaults to 50 entries
    
    // execute query and return records
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    $number = mysql_num_rows($result);
    
    // display the results
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo '<div class="log-entry"><pre>';
        echo 'Error: '.htmlspecialchars($row['error']);
        echo ' - '.htmlspecialchars($row['logtime'])."\n";
        echo 'Request: '.$website.htmlspecialchars($row['request'])."\n";
        echo 'User Agent: '.htmlspecialchars($row['agent'])."\n";
        echo 'IP Address: '.htmlspecialchars($row['address']);
        echo '</pre></div>';
    }
    
    //close db connection
    mysql_close($dbhandle);
    ?>
```

**Step 6**

Create dynamic logging page

Finally, create a file named “AjaxErrorLog.html” and insert the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Ajax Error Log</title>
        <!-- Ajax Error Log @ https://perishablepress.com/ajax-error-log/ -->
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <style>
            pre {
                font: 10px/1.5 Courier, "Courier New", mono;
                background-color: #efefef; border: 1px solid #ccc;
                width: 700px; margin: 7px; padding: 10px;
                white-space: pre-wrap;
                }
        </style>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#results").load("AjaxErrorLog.php");
                var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
                    $("#results").load("AjaxErrorLog.php").fadeIn("slow");
                }, 2000); // refresh time (default = 2000 ms = 2 seconds)
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <noscript><div id="response"><h1>JavaScript is required for this demo.</h1></div></noscript>
        <div id="results"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

"This is the page that will display the results dynamically in a browser. It’s a basic web page that uses a little jQuery/Ajax magic to load the output of the AjaxErrorLog.php file and refresh the results every two seconds (as specified in the code as “2000”). Feel free to use any refresh interval you wish, just keep in mind that these are server requests, so don’t go too crazy."